# How to add multiple projects in one solution in VS2008 Web Developer Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I been using VS2008 Pro for a long time now but since of licensing issues(Pro is under academic license) and the current project I am doing could be considered as commerial I decided to give VS2008 Express a go.

Now I made my project and a shell of all my pages. I went to add a class library to my solution so I can start adding my nunit tests but I noticed they don't have add a new project to solution button anywhere.

So how do I do this?

Edit

Never mind I found it. They seemed to have removed it from right clicking on your solution then going "add new Project".

You have to go to "File->Add->New/Existing Project".

Comment: You could always purchase a commercial licence for Visual Studio. Failing that, you could just create a virtual PC and install Visual Studio 2010 on it, and delete it once you've finished the project.

Comment: Ya well I don't have $1,069.99CAD lying around to spend on Visual Studios. 

As with Visual Studios 2010 I don't want to use a beta product.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Also you'll have to check this checkbox to see the solution:
Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General->Always Show Solution

Comment: Thanks! I was going crazy, the solution was disappearing every time!